# Threading a shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have a small shell script that executes ~30 Java commands consecutively. Each one pulls data from a MySQL db then jams it into a BI tool. Is there any way to execute >1 of these commands from within said shell script? Unfortunately, I only have access to the script itself, I cannot change the frequency or method of execution.

THANKS

Comment: Which shell executes the script? Is job control enabled? Can the tool handle incoming data concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a construct like this:

```
command_1 &
command_2 &
command_3 &
# ...

wait
```

will run all of the commands with `&` at the end in parallel, and then wait for all of them to finish before continuing.  Without knowing more about what these commands look like, I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Zack. That might be exactly what I needed.